# connect QuickBooks IPP to QuickBooks Online with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, quickbooks-online

I am developing `RubyOnRails` application.

My company uses `QuickBooks Online`, and I would like to write some Rails code that using `create customer, invoices` etc..

Therefore, I created a `QuickBooks IPP account` (at developer.intuit.com).

Now, how do I connect/point my QuickBooks IPP account to my company's QuickBooks Online subscription?

If any gem is best then which gem should be use which have full options.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I see from another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402517/integration-quickbook-online-api-to-rails-app) that you found the [quickbooks-ruby](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby) gem but wanted to make sure this question was answered properly.

Disclaimer: I [contribute](https://github.com/ruckus/quickbooks-ruby/graphs/contributors) regularly to the gem but that aside, it is the only gem in town for Ruby/QBO v3 integration.

Moreover, I have created a 3-part [tutorial and screencast](http://minimul.com/integrating-rails-and-quickbooks-online-via-the-version-3-api-part-1.html) series demonstrating integrating a Rails app with the new version 3 QuickBooks API, which answers your question "how do I connect/point my QuickBooks IPP account to my company's QuickBooks Online subscription?" and many more questions to jump start a Rails (or Ruby)/ QuickBooks integration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have oauth token to communicate with your QB account.

You can follow the steps below to generate Oauth tokens.

To get consumerkey, consumerSecret and apptoken - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0010_signup

To get accessToken and accessSecret corresponding to your QBO account - https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth/IA/
Then download the devkit from this link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits

Using OAuthTokens [ consumerkye, consumerSecret, accessToken , accessSecret ] and RelamId(QBO account), you can connect to your QBO account. Using any standard gem(which I don't know now) you should construct OAuth header and make a successful call.
As of now, IPP provides examples only in java/.net/PHP.

If you just want to explorer all the REST V3 APIs, then you can use ApiExplorer tool as well( It doesn't need any OAuth tokens.)

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Thanks